# Boat motor rattles oarlock horns

Tags: boats

I have [oarlock horns](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/zinc-plated-clamp-on-oarlock-horns-for-kayak-or-canoe-2-pk-0792473p.0792473.html?rq=oar#srp) attached to the oars of my aluminum boat.

[image]

They make a terrible racket when I use my [2.5 hp Mercury outboard motor](https://www.mercurymarine.com/en/ca/engines/outboard/fourstroke/25-25hp/). The vibrations from the motor travel through the boat and rattle the oarlock horn brackets against the bolts.

(I place the oars inside the boat on the seats when I'm using the motor; I don't store the oars in place in the rowlocks. Reason: It's awkward to store  the oars in the rowlocks and prop the paddle-end up against the transom.)

---

I've been able to stop the rattling by wrapping the oarlock horns with [gear ties](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/nite-ize-gear-tie-reusable-rubber-twist-tie-12-inch-2-pack-bright-orange/1001572851) (large rubber twist ties):

[image]

That works, but it's a nuisance to unwrap and wrap them every time I want to use the oars. I use the oars when launching and returning to shore multiple times per outing.

---

Is there a more convenient way to prevent the oarlock horns from rattling? Or a different kind of oarlock horn that wouldn't have rattling parts -- but is still suitable for novice rowers?

Related: [Reduce vibration transferred from outboard motor to aluminum boat](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/93427/reduce-vibration-transferred-from-outboard-motor-to-aluminum-boat)

Comment: I know you said the rattle was from the horn along the bolt - but could it be the pin against the oar? If so, pad the oar or stow with pins dangling down?

Comment: Maybe try a different motor mount or add non-absorbent fireproof padding to the existing one?  Just thinking aloud...